# bash script end loop if true

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array of numbers (1 2 3 4 5)

```
magicnumber=7
```

I want to say if the magic number is equal to a number found in the array or greater than the highest number in the array then do.

{array[@]} - contains numbers

```
highnum=the highest number from the array

for f in $dir   "#f is file with a number in it"
do 

    "the number inside file f is pulled out and named filenum"
    filenum

    for i in ${array[@]}
    do
        if [ $i -eq $filenum ] || [ $filenum -gt $highnum ]
        then 
            do this and end the "for i loop"
        else
            continue with loop
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To indent the code, write it in the text edit box (or paste it) as you want it to appear — no tabs.  Then select the code and press the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent all by 4 spaces.

Comment: The `break` statement terminates the loop.  The `else` clause is redundant since the loop will continue anyway.  However, you could use `continue` in the `else` clause to go to the next cycle of the loop.

Comment: If I am looping in a loop will it break both or just the last loop?

Comment: @user2561395: Typing `help break` in a bash shell will provide faster feedback then adding comments to an SO question.

Comment: On its own, `break` breaks a single loop; to break 2 levels of loop, you'd say `break 2`.  Similarly with `continue`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "array stringification" and pattern matching to determine if the magic number is in the array -- All the quotes and spaces below are very deliberate and necessary.

```
if [[ " ${array[*]} " == *" $magicnumber "* ]]; then
    echo "magic number is in array"
else
    # Otherwise, find the maximum value in the array 
    max=${array[0]}
    for (( i=1; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
        (( ${array[i]} > max )) && max=${array[i]}
    done
    (( magicnumber > max )) && echo "magic number greater than array elements"
fi
```